# How to resize a BitmapImage from another BitmapImage in memory and not on filesystem

Tags: c#, wpf, resize, bitmapimage

This is the continuation of

> [Datacontract serialization/serialization with images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35671829/datacontract-serialization-serialization-with-images)

so now I have a BitmapImage coming from a stream. In short a BitmapImage
I want to resize it to a desired size.

I have found tons of code on how to resize from an image on file system but none on how to resize from an already existing BitmapImage

EDIT:
[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may use a `TransformedBitmap` with an appropriate `ScaleTransform`:

```
BitmapImage sourceBitmap = ...
var targetBitmap = new TransformedBitmap(sourceBitmap, new ScaleTransform(0.5, 0.5));
```

The result is a TransformedBitmap, not a BitmapImage. However, this shouldn't matter, because in your application there should be no need to deal only with BitmapImages. It should be sufficient to do all image-related stuff with the base classes `BitmapSource` or even `ImageSource`, which is the type of the `Source` property of the Image control.

Comment: TransformedBitmap wants a bitmapSource and not bitmapImage. It doesn't build and no easy cast is allowed

Comment: BitmapImage is derived from BitmapSource. You can pass a BitmapImage to every method that accepts a BitmapSource argument

Comment: Please see my add. And then can Tranform use pixels instead than percent?

Comment: `targetBitmap` should be of type `BitmapSource`, not `BitmapImage`.

Comment: The scale factors can be calculated by elementary math. Divide the desired width/height by the actual width/height of the source bitmap, as shown e.g. here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18189949/1136211

Comment: So the problem is that: if I don't use the word ref for destination e.g.  ResizeBmpSize(BitmapImage source, BitmapSource destination, int width, int height) the bmp is properly resized but not brought out of the s/r.  If I use the word ref it get an error: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1503 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'ref System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage' to 'ref System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource'